# python/pandas changing the values of columns conditinally according to plusier columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

my df is something like this;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['BSS'],
                   'activity':[np.nan],
                   'division':['BSS'],
                   'site':['Tanger']})
```

i want to take the value of column 'division' which is 'BSS' and put it into column activity if only division is 'BSS'. I managed it by `df.loc[df['Division'] == 'BSS', 'Activity'] = 'BSS'`but while i am doing it i also want to insert the value 'europe' into column 'division' if only column 'site' is 'Tanger'

I tried `if`  and  `else` but didin't worked out.

```
# if division == "BSS" and site == "Tanger":
#    df["Activity"].fillna("BSS") and df["Division"].replace("Europe")
```

didn't worked out.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it a two steps process, and be sure what you want to get because the order is important. Suppose you have one row of your df as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'entity':['BSS'],
                   'activity':[np.nan],
                   'division':['BSS'],
                   'site':['Tanger']})
```

Now, if you implement the double `.loc` substitution, the order of the steps change the output:

```
df.loc[df['division'] == 'BSS', 'activity'] = 'BSS'
df.loc[df['site'] == 'Tanger', 'division'] = 'Europe'
```

output1:

```
entity         BSS
activity       BSS
division    Europe
site        Tanger
```

On the other hand

```
df.loc[df['site'] == 'Tanger', 'division'] = 'Europe'
df.loc[df['division'] == 'BSS', 'activity'] = 'BSS'
```

output2:

```
entity         BSS
activity       NaN
division    Europe
site        Tanger
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works like this, first changing division to activity and afterwards europe to division. But the thing is something like `if` and `else` would be more time saving because i have like 260 files like this and if i write double `.loc` for each of them it would take more time to execute and etc.

Comment: @Pyx and imburningbabe, I solved it by using `.isin` and entered all the conditions in a list and it worked out. but it takes 2 steps as imburningbabe suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'entity': ['BSS - Tanger'],
    'activity': [''],
    'division': ['BSS'],
    'site': ['Tanger'],
})

# First part
def my_function(x):
    if x == 'BSS':
        return 'BSS'
    return ''

my_df.loc[:,'activity'] = list(map(
    lambda x: my_function(x),
    my_df['division'].tolist()
))

# second part 
def my_function_2(x, prev_value):
    if x == 'Tanger':
        return 'europe'
    return prev_value

my_df.loc[:,'division'] = list(map(
    lambda x, prev_value: my_function_2(x, prev_value),
    my_df['site'].tolist(),
    my_df['division'].tolist(),
    
))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pyx, i tried your solution. for the df in the example it worked out but as  i have 260 files having different 'divison', 'activity' and 'site', it a little broke my fucntion dictionary where i embeded yours. Maybe it is because of me, i don't know.